# Google IAP using Node certificate has expired error?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-auth-library, google-auth-library-nodejs

I have a node server which needs to connect to an IAP (Identity Aware Proxy) protected API endpoint. The below example from Google seems to be fine expect for the `certificate has expired` error. I believe I simply need to send `rejectUnauthorized: false` along with the request, but I am not sure how to implement it.

### Update

I was able to force it to work with adding `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` but it is my understanding that this option is more insecure compared to `rejectUnauthorized: false`. Any insight?

```
'use strict';

const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');

const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');
const oauth2Keys = require('./iap.keys.json');

async function main() {
  const clientId = oauth2Keys.web.client_id;
  const client = new JWT({
    email: keys.client_email,
    key: keys.private_key,
    additionalClaims: {target_audience: clientId},
  });
  const url = `https://iap-demo-dot-el-gato.appspot.com`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Link to the Google Example: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/502f43e651d7ccbd1cc19de513d5f5af5008ac03/samples/iap.js

Comment: Can you post the details on the expired certificate? I am interested in `Issued to`, `Isued by` and `Valid from` fields plus the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` disables the SSL certificate check.